# UHF Band-pass Filter - Is it bidirectional? SMA connector convention?

Tags: rf, filter

I have this [1090MHz Band-pass SMA Filter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010GBQXK8).  It did not ship with a datasheet.

Is such a device bidirectional? i.e. is there an in and out?  Is there a directional convention using SMA male and female connectors?

I have a collection of SMA adapters and am confused with the combinations of male and female barrels each with both male or female cores.

Thank you.

Comment: If you look at the amazon comments http://www.amazon.com/dp/B010GBQXK8/?tag=stackoverfl08-20#Ask the manufacturer answered that the male connector was the output

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I am uncertain whether the gender refers to the inner contact pin or to the barrel of the connector.  The label itself is not marked with direction.

Comment: Male/female refers to the inner connector shape. For SMA, male would be the one with the rotating part.

Comment: By the way is this intended to be connected directly to the antenna ? Because it will likely increase to global receiver's noise factor and do more harm than good. I suggest you put a 1090 MHz LNA (Low Noise Amplifier) instead which will act as a filter and also amplify the received signal !

Comment: I have a multiband antenna on a mast to try the filter.  Thanks for your advice, I also have a dedicated antenna for 1090 and will look into the LNA for it.

Comment: @MaximGi unless there is strong adjacent channel interference, when the filter is to stop the LNA overload and wrecking the signal. It all depends on the local radio environment.

Answer (score 2):

The filter is not directional. Passive filters are inherently reversible, though not always cascadable.

The different connectors on either end do not imply any particular direction, they are simply to allow the filter to be dropped in at the end of a cable as a bolt-on, often as part of troubleshooting.

Male is the connector with the pin in the middle.

If you are only using it to try and listen in to some transponder signals while you are on the ground, then this will work fine. ADS-B usually has quite a generous link budget owing to the massive Tx power of the transmitters.